# problem with counter of collision of two imageViews

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, uiimageview, collision-detection

here is my code:

```
-(void)moveTheImage{
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [views count]; i++) {
    imageView = [views objectAtIndex:i];
    X = [[XArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
    Y = [[YArray objectAtIndex:i] floatValue];
imageView.center=CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + X, imageView.center.y + Y);
    [self interaction];

}
```

}

```
-(void)interaction{
if(!intersectFlag)
{   



    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame))    
    {
        intersectFlag = YES;    
        label.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", counti];
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        ++counti;
    }
}
else
{
    if(!CGRectIntersectsRect(imageView.frame,centre.frame))
    {
        intersectFlag = NO;
    }
}
```

}
I want that the count increase of 1 every time there is a collision between "imageView" and "centre" but my problem is that the count increase too much,more exactly it increase for "imageView"  in "centre" then when it doesn't touch "centre" the counter stops.How can I solve this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0):

If "intersectFlag" marks the state of a single imageView object then it should be a member of that object and not shared between all imageViews.

Comment: I don't really understand can you explain more please ?